# Why is my selection sort algorithm consistently faster than my insertion sort?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, time

*"Sorted" is a randomly generated, initially unsorted array of integers*

```
private void insertion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for(int i = 1; i < Sorted.Length; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        while(j>0 && Sorted[j-1] > Sorted[j])
        {
            swap(Sorted, j - 1, j);
            j -= 1;
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();

    IsSorted = true;
    UpdateButtons(IsSorted);
    MessageBox.Show($"Insertion sort took {(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString()} milliseconds", "Insertion sort");
}


//Selection sort
private void selection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for(int i = 0; i < Sorted.Length-1; i++)
    {
        int CurrMinIndex = i;
        for(int j = i; j < Sorted.Length; j++)
        {
            if(Sorted[j] < Sorted[CurrMinIndex])
            {
                CurrMinIndex = j;
            }
        }

        if(CurrMinIndex != i)
        {
            swap(Sorted, CurrMinIndex, i);
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();

    IsSorted = true;
    UpdateButtons(IsSorted);
    MessageBox.Show($"Selection sort took {(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString()} milliseconds", "Selection Sort");
}
```

I'm designing a C# WPF application that does sorts on randomly generated lists and then outputs the time in milliseconds that it took to complete. I know Insertion Sort is supposed to be, on average, better than selection sort, but my results tell me otherwise. I have not seen even once that the timing for insertion sort came close to selection sort. In fact, it seems that my selection sort algorithm is consistently twice as fast! Does anyone see the problem here? I thought that I had done some pretty general forms of the two algorithms, but did I accidently optimize?

Edit: Here is the algorithm I am using to populate my list:

```
Sorted = new int[ListSize];  //initialize/populate unsorted array
Random Rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < ListSize; i++)
{
     Sorted[i] = Rand.Next(-1000, 1000);
}
```

Comment: How long is the list to be sorted? Also initial ordering will make a difference (reversing array as you appear to do is a special case for complexity, eg. pure quick sort is very bad in that case).

Comment: It's completely random. A user is prompted to enter an integer value of the size they want, such as 2000 or 22399, etc, and a random list is generated and stored, which can then by sorted with whichever algorithm they want. I updated my post to show how I am populating the list.

Comment: @Evk: Selection sort is not significantly faster on an already-sorted array because it still has to do all `(n^2 -n)/2` comparisons. It doesn't do any swaps, but there's no early out.

Comment: They're reset for sure. I can check too with the click of a button on my application.

Comment: @JimMischel but I mean if you first sort completely random array with insertion sort, and then you apply selection sort to this (already sorted) array - it should be faster than insertion sort on random array, right?

Comment: @Evk: I wouldn't expect it to be faster. Selection sort on a sorted array takes almost as much time as on an unsorted array.

Comment: After thinking about this I'm not so sure insertion sort should be faster than selection on random filled array. Yes it requires less comparisions on average but on the other hand it requires more writes (swaps) on average than selection sort. On the other hand, if you have at least partially sorted array (say you add a range of sorted items [1001, 1002...] to the end of initial array in your case) - then insertion sort should be faster.

Comment: And yet, insertion sort has been shown to be faster than selection sort. Note also that an optimized insertion sort won't do individual swaps, as shown by MBo in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insertion sort implementation is not good enough. You make full swaps while looking for a place for element P, but it is enough to remember P, shift larger elements up (half-swaps?), then insert P

```
     int j = i;
     int P = Sorted[j];
     while(j>0 && Sorted[j-1] > P)
        {
            Sorted[j] = Sorted [j-1];
            j--;
        };
    Sorted[j] = P;
```

Comment: Hmm. That code is giving me an OutOfBounds exception

Comment: My mistake, should be `Sorted[j] = P;`

Comment: Ahh, Thank you very much. That seemed to do the trick. I'm still a little unsure about something though. If I had to optimize Insertion sort for my program, does that mean that my selection sort algorithm was optimized? I thought that I had used pretty basic versions of these algorithms, so i am unsure why there was such a difference in time.

Comment: Your selection sort is optimal. Note that selection always makes predefined number of compares (n*(n-1)/2). Number of compares for insertion sort depends on data set order, and in average is less.